# vue-router history mode doesn't work on refresh

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js, vue-router

I added *vue-router* to my project and it works fine with basic settings. But I want to get rid of the hashtag (#) in the URL. So following [the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) I switch to history mode. I works great with this link (`<router-link to="/page/4">Open page</router-link>`) but if I try to access this page directly (refresh) the server returns 404 error screen.

I use *nginx* (docker's *nginx:alpine* image) and this is the *default* file:

```
server {
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

And this is the router:

```
new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/page/:id',
      component: page
    }
  ],
});
```

Why it returns 404 error?

Comment: Not a solution, just a sidenote: the `router-link` works because it's a pushState, not a real request to that URL (so it doesn't go to the server). The real request is made when you navigate directly or refresh.

Comment: When using history mode, you need to make sure your server returns the index page for any server request. You would need to configure this on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

It's nginx configuration issue 
Insert config below to your nginx server block/config

```
error_page 404 /index.html;
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly,

On your route.js file add:

```
{
    path: '/*',
    redirect: { name: 'route-name' }
}
```

This will redirect all the invalid route to the route you desire to.

Secondly, On your web.php file in Laravel:

```
Route::get('/{any}', function() { return view('your-main-view'); })->where('any', '(.*)');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a catch all route when using history mode. Vue-router is for client side routing, where as when you directly access the url in a browser, it's attempting to route through your server, hence the 404.

With Laravel, for example, you would define the catch all route like this:

```
// match all GET or HEAD requests and return the my-app.index.blade.php file
Route::get('/{view?}', 'HomeController@index')
     ->where('view', '(.*)')
     ->name('my-app.index');
```

This will match any route GET or HEAD request and return the main view page. Within that page is the JavaScript application and vue-router will then act accordingly.

However, now your app will never show a 404, so to properly display a 404 page, you need to create another catch all in your js routes. See the Caveat section at the end of the page:

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Edit:

```
// nginx redirect 
location / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: I use vue for client side (no PHP) and index.html is the place where I expect to handle all requests. But it looks like the nginx doesn't redirect the user to mysite.com/index.html when it try to load mysite.com/page/1. That is what I want to do.

Comment: Added nginx redirect to answer

Comment: Unfortunately Iit doesn't change anything. :/